# Why is "s" doesn't return anything?

Tags: python

The program is not returning anything, Why?

```
def g(n): 
    s=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i == 0:
           s = s+1
    return(s)
n = int(input("enter g value : "))
```

Comment: This is not valid Python, you cannot return outside a function.

Comment: Did you mess up your formatting? Or perhaps cut off your definition by accident?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code isn't legal.

Comment: A program does not *return*. A function does. Maybe you mean *print*? you need to call your function like `g(n)` and then print its returned value. Like: `print(g(n))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To return something you have to define a function. 
You can write it as following

```
def Func(n):      
    s=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            s = s+1
    return(s)
```

Then you can use the following to get the value of n

```
n = int(input("enter g value : "))

value_of_s = Func(n)
print(value_of_s)
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the OP accidentally omitted code; the code posted would die immediately with `SyntaxError`, not just silently do nothing. This likely isn't answering the OP's question.

Comment: True. But i explained how to create a function if the person doesn't know that.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed @Vikika, I don't really know much about functions

Comment: @SS2 No Issue. If you want to return something create function and also your logic was a bit off. First learn about functions and then create one.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Look this is what i was trying to do. I think you can upvote my answer now

Comment: The problem was not about defining the function. It was that the function was never called... Notice that comparing to OP, you simply changed the function's name.  Also, from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45): *Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores*

Comment: @Tomerikoo He edited the post. Initially he didn;t defined that. And i haven't simply changed the name. i actually called the function.

Comment: But your whole first part of the answer is about changing the name of the function...

Comment: Initially there was no name given to the function. It was simply the body of function.There i wrote a name and defined it to show, how to define a function. Nevermind!! Thanks for pointing the wrong things